# Detect all kinds of vegetables and fruits values within a column

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to figure out i if there's a more efficient way to detect all the vegetables and fruits that exists within data contained in a certain column in this Google Sheets test [Test 1](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sZQDcfzej2gsle7YGEhIYP_LFluDaGM_dEXcklxXBbY/edit?usp=sharing). I have tried some "manual" ways with queries like adding a certain number of identified vegs & fruits like this:

```
=arrayformula(regexreplace(first cell in first row ;"(?i)car|mother|boxes|houses|person"; "") )
```

It seems to work fine, but I think it might be a more efficient way since there are many other fruits and vegs in the text and some of them even in other language, moreover I want to delete those commas left in the clean column. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can try below formula-

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ";1;INDEX(QUERY(FLATTEN(TRIM(SPLIT(A3;",")));
"select Col1 where not Col1 matches 'machines|cold treatment|red car|houses|person|airplanes|ferrari|refrigerator'";0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! That seems like a more efficient way to get rid of those commas and spaces, but do you recommend a better way to avoid inserting a lot of manual words when it comes to large data sets?

Comment: Then you have to insert those list to a separate sheet and use another `TEXTJOIN()` to match those list to `QUERY()` formula.

Comment: Something like `=TEXTJOIN(", ";1;INDEX(QUERY(FLATTEN(TRIM(SPLIT(A3;",")));"select Col1 where not Col1 matches '" & TEXTJOIN("|";1;'Hoja 2'!A:A) & "'";0)))` Where `'Hoja 2'!A:A` is your list.

Comment: Thank you Harun! That seemed to work really well